# Compression possibilities for specific long array

Tags: compression

I have a file which is nothing but an array of longs (8-byte integers).
I know that each consecutive long is larger in value than its predecessor.

What simple and complicated ways are there to compress this data?

What I have thought of:

Assessing the largest difference and storing only the difference between the longs, assuming it takes fewer bits per long to represent the difference.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If I look at the ensemble of sequences with that non-increasing property, then I would be able to compress out on average 1 of every 64 bits, i.e. about 1.5% compression. Not very impressive. You would need to provide more information on the distribution of the deltas, and other properties of the data (e.g. is there some degree of "smoothness" expected, so that a fit of curves to two or more preceding elements, might be useful in predicting the next element?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, your idea seems correct.

Let's say you have L<sub>0</sub> .. L<sub>1</sub> ... L<sub>n-1</sub> .. L<sub>n</sub> your n unsigned longs, such as
L<sub>k+1</sub> >= L<sub>k</sub>, and obviously by definition L<sub>0</sub> >= 0 and L<sub>k</sub> <= L<sub>max</sub>.

Let's call diff<sub>k</sub> = L<sub>k+1</sub> - L<sub>k</sub> the difference function which represents the data you plan on compressing.

If we study the sum of diff<sub>0</sub> .. diff<sub>1</sub> ... diff<sub>n-2</sub> .. diff<sub>n-1</sub> :

diff<sub>0</sub> + diff<sub>1</sub> + .. + diff<sub>n-2</sub> + diff<sub>n-1</sub> = L<sub>1</sub> - L<sub>0</sub> + L<sub>2</sub> - L<sub>1</sub> + .. + L<sub>n-1</sub> - L<sub>n-2</sub> + L<sub>n</sub> - L<sub>n-1</sub>,

This simplifies to L<sub>n</sub> - L<sub>0</sub> : the sum of all differences is equal to L<sub>n</sub> - L<sub>0</sub>.

So on average the function diff<sub>n</sub> has a value of (L<sub>n</sub> - L<sub>0</sub>) / (n - 1), whereas L<sub>k</sub> has an average value of (L<sub>n</sub> - L<sub>0</sub>) / 2.

As n >> 2, we can therefore say that average(diff<sub>n</sub>) << average(L<sub>n</sub>), which means you **will need less bits** to compress the diff<sub>n</sub> information.

As of how to do such a compression, without more information on the data distribution it's difficult to assess what the best possible algorithm could be.
You can start with a trivial scheme like this :

if(diff<sub>k</sub> < 128) return a byte with the first bit set, and the 7 remaining bits containing the value of diff<sub>k</sub>
else if(diff<sub>k</sub> < 16384) return a byte with the first bit unset, and the 7 remaining bits containing the first 7 bits of the value of diff<sub>k</sub>, then another byte with the first bit set and the 7 bits remaining containing the rest of the value of diff<sub>k</sub>, etc...

To decompress it's very easy, you read a byte, if the first bit is set, you know you only need to read the next 7 bits, if not, you read and store 7 bits and you go on to the next byte, etc.